# How to download file attachment in browser from physical path

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm currently working on a project for my company and ive encountered a problem. I dont know why I cant download the file attachment.

Ive attached a jpg file of the screenshot below for you to see. There is a file attachment named sad kermit(2).jpg and a message in the console in the screenshot. I was expecting a download feature somewhere on the sad kermit(2).jpg but its not there.

I'm using mvc and kendo jquery. This is my kendo form code in view.

```
$("#form").kendoForm({
        validatable: { validationSummary: true },
        orientation: "horizontal",
        formData: {
            ID: "@Model.ID",
            IssueNumber: "@Model.ISSUE_NUM",
            Title: "@Model.TITLE",
            Environment: "@Model.ENVIRONMENT",
            Application: "@Model.APPLICATION",
            Module: "@Model.MODULE",
            Priority: "@Model.PRIORITY",
            Status: "@Model.STATUS",
            FID: "@Model.FID",
            Jobname: "@Model.JOBNAME",
            Username: "@Model.USERNAME",
            MantisNumber: "@Model.MANTIS_NO",
            ModifiedBy: "@ViewBag.User_Name",
            Upload: "",
            ModifiedDate: "@Model.MODIFIED_DATE",
            Description: "@Model.DESCRIPTION",
            IssueType: "@Model.ISSUE_TYPE",
            IssueCategory: "@Model.ISSUE_CATEGORY",
            IssueResolution: "@Model.ISSUE_RESOLUTION",
            Remarks: "@Model.REMARKS",
            AssignedTo: "@Model.ASSIGNED_TO",
            CreatedBy: "@ViewBag.User_Name"
        },
        items: [{
            type: "group",
            label: "Edit Issue Details",
            items: [
                ...,
               ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
               ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                {
                    field: "Upload",
                    label: "Upload File:",
                    editor: function (container, options) {
                        $("<input name='files' id='files' type='file' aria-label='files' />").appendTo(container).kendoUpload({
                            async: {
                                saveUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Issue")',
                                removeUrl: '@Url.Action("RemoveFiles", "Issue")',
                                autoUpload: true
                            },
                            files: uploads
                        });
                    }
                },
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
            ]
            }],
            submit: function (ev)...
        });
```

this is the code I use to try to download the file attachment in the same view but it isnt working I guess

```
$(".k-file").click(function (e) {
            var filename = $(this).find(".k-file-name").html();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { "name": filename },
                url: "/Issue/DownloadFile",
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.Success) {
                        console.log(res.DownloadUrl);
                        window.open(res.DownloadUrl, '_blank');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

this is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(string name)
    {
        var folderName = Session["IssueNum"] as string;

        string fileDirectory = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data", folderName, name);

        return Json(new
        {
            Success = true,
            DownloadUrl = fileDirectory
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Could you suggest me a solution?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your browser can preview the file then it will not be downloaded. You can try below code. I've modified a part of your code.

```
$(".k-file").click(function (e) {
            var filename = $(this).find(".k-file-name").html();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { "name": filename },
                url: "/Issue/DownloadFile",
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.Success) {
                        console.log(res.DownloadUrl);
                        //window.open(res.DownloadUrl, '_blank');
                        var link = document.createElement("a"); 
                      link.setAttribute('download', ""); 
                      link.setAttribute('href', res.DownloadUrl); 
                      link.href = url; 
                      document.body.appendChild(link); 
                      link.click(); 
                      link.remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```